# How to select MongoDB indexes for complex queries

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Answering this question, probably, involves multiple issues, so it should be fun :)
So, I have

1. a collection with fields `{a, a1, s, i, j}`.
2. field `a1` always has the same value as `a`
3. value of field `s` is always the same (static)
4. I will use only two types of queries:
5. find(a=a, a1=a, s=s, i=i)
6. find(a=a, a1=a, s=s, j=j)

Which index(es) should be created and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create two compound indexes for the best performance

one should be { a, a1, s, i }
the other should be { a, a1, s, j }

Why? For best performance, you can include all the fields of the most used queries, in this case, the query .5 and .6

An essential fact of the compound indexes is that you can use the index if your query has attributes that are part of an index prefix. So, if you have a compounded index (a,b,c,d) a prefix can be:

- a
- a, b
- a, b, c
- a, b, c, d

so if you have the index (a,b,c,d) and you have a query for find(a=a) the query will use the index.

if you have the index (a,b,c,d) and you have a query for find(b=b, c=c) the query will not use the index.

if you have the index (a,b,c,d) and you have a query for find(a=a, c=c) the query will use the index but not with the best performance because will do a full scan in a way to do the comparison for the c attribute.

The order of the find operation doesn't matter but the order of the compound index matters.

Compound indexes: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/

Comment: Is it correct that for `find(a=a, c=c)` MongoDB first will use index by `a` and then do full scan over results by `c`?

Comment: yep, you are right!

Comment: So, taking into account `a1=a` and `s=constant` if skip them from the index, it will not worsen things due to after searching the index there will be only 1 option already?

Comment: wait if you skip a1 and s from the index and you try to find by find(a=a, a1=a, s=s, i=i) that will have bad performance because you will  do a full scan for a1, s and i
the best index will be the one that I wrote in the response

The thing here is how many attributes will do a full scan. If your query needs to do a full scan frequently or the full scan is for more than two attributes you should have an index

in this case the two compound indexes that I sent you will solve your problem